# Running MVC with exisiting Webforms site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

I read have most if not all of the various articles on adding MVC 3 to existing webforms sites. I have made the changes to the webforms site's global asax to support MVC as well changes to web.config. However there are still some issues.

1. MVC 3 is greedy - By default it takes over the root of the site so that navigate to the root i go to the entry page for mvc and not the webforms page which is what i want. To be clear when navigating to the root, i want it to go to mysite.com/default.aspx. To fix site root i add

   routes.MapPageRoute("SiteRoot", "", "~/Default.aspx")
   However this then breaks the MVC urls such that i end up with messed up urls like

   http://localhost:86/default?action=Index&controller=Blog
   How can i fix it so that the site root goes to webforms default.aspx and still have my MVC urls be correct?
2. MVC 3 breaks a ccouple of HttpHandlers that the webform uses. Specifically, I use a handler to add far future expires headers to images and a resource handler to combine stylesheets and javascript files. The sheer presence of any route in RegisterRoutes breaks these handlers so that stylesheets dont load via the resource handler, and i lose the far future expires, and there is a httpcompression module that stops working too. So how do I maintain my httphandlers and modules for the webforms while still retaining the routes for MVC 3 portion of the site?

These 2 issues i have not seen anyone address in the various blog posts regarding mixing MVC3 and webforms.

Oh and i have **routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}") in global.asax.** The resource handler uses an aspx file extension so I would think then withthis exclusion in global that the hanlder would work but i guess not.

Another option i know is to set up a folder inside the wbeforms site and run it as its own appllication starting point - however i end up with a url i dont really want such as site.com/blog/blog/index where the 1st blog is the folder running as its own application point and the second blog is the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution that I can find is to **not** mix MVC 3 with the existing webforms site. Instead set the MVC directory as its own app starting point and then run the MVC from that folder so that it and the existing webforms app are completely ignorant of each other. In this fashion, the resource handler and httpmodules and other handlers all still work for the webforms site. And this way the domain root goes to webforms default.aspx and not MVC by default. Also i dont have to put that entry into global.asax which in turn screwed up the mvc 3 urls. The next issue was to deal with the urls so that i didnt have a url lke blog/blog/post/1. To fix this i changed the html action link to

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.PostTitle, "Post", New With {.id = item.PostId}, Nothing)
```

And then make a change to global.asax - change the default route to (simply delete {controller}:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
        "Default", _
        "{action}/{id}", _
        New With {.controller = "Blog", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}, New String() {"RiderDesignMvcBlog.Core.Controllers"})
```

So now instead of blog/blog/index or blog/blog/post/1 i get a proper clean url without the duplicate blog in the url - blog/post/1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change the extension of your handler as a true handler, `.ASHX`, and ignore them instead.